# How to download the multiple bokeh images as a single report

Tags: django, python-3.x, bokeh

My application is hosted on Django and one of the html pages shows multiple bar graphs which are drawn using Bokeh. I know we can download each graph separately by using SaveTool icon which comes with Bokeh.

Now my requirement is I want to have a export button in the page, when I click on export button, all the images should be downloaded in a single pdf file or any other format what ever is the easier option to implement.

Please guide me how can I achieve this?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Bokeh server application, you could use the [`export_png`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/export.html#png-generation) function. However, it sounds like it is a Bokeh server application, in which case there is nothing built-in for this. It looks like there is a [JavaScript API for screen capture](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/export.html#png-generation). So you could try using that API in a [`CustomJS` callback](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#customjs-for-user-interaction-events) for a `Button`. Note that for security reasons that API will make make users provide active consent every time before allowing a screenshot to be taken.

Comment: Thanks @bigreddot for the reply, I will look into the solution you mentioned.